# Android Buttons not always visible when they should be

Tags: android, android-button

Does anyone have any advice on what I should do about buttons that aren't always responding properly to `button.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE)`?

I've watched my code run step-by-step in the debugger.  The line is definitely being executed, but the button just isn't always changing from invisible to visible.

There's no error message, and the `setVisibility()` command is being executed inside a `runOnUiThread()`.  Also, I'm doing my best to carefully manage my threads, so I don't think it's a there's an issue with commands being run before they should be.

Has anybody got any idea??

Thanks,
R.

In response to eminently reasonable requests, I'm adding the following description and code (what's "alpha channel", anyway?)

My application is essentially an Android SurfaceRunner.  On start up, the active surface is plugged into my XML layout that defines my buttons.  Some of the buttons are outside the SurfaceRunner and some are on top of it.  It's the ones one top that are giving me the problems (if that's significant).  However, I should also point out they're also the only ones that start invisible in my code -- starting invisible seems to be the problem.  I've never experienced an problems with any of my buttons that start visible.  BTW, none of the buttons are tagged as invisible in the XML

Button display is handled with a method called `lblButtons()` that's called every time something is done that might affect the buttons.  It's a lot of code, so I'm only including the sections here that aren't working properly:

```
rtButton2.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);       
rtButton2.setTextColor (DF_VIEW == currState ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
rtButton2.setBackgroundDrawable (DF_VIEW == currState ? tr_black : tr_white);
if (currState == SEARCH_VIEW)
{
    rtButton2.setTextSize (24f);
    rtButton2.setText (Html.fromHtml (Integer.toString (app.currThr)));
    rtButton2.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
}
else if (listening) 
{
    rtButton2.setTextSize (14f);
    rtButton2.setText (Html.fromHtml (muting ? UNMUTE : MUTE));
    rtButton2.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
}

rtButton3.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
rtButton3.setTextSize (14f);
rtButton3.setTextColor (DF_VIEW == currState ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
rtButton3.setBackgroundDrawable (DF_VIEW == currState ? tr_black : tr_white);
if (listening)
{
    rtButton3.setText (Html.fromHtml (recording ? STOP + "<br />" + RECORD : RECORD));
    rtButton3.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
}
```

"listening" is a Boolean, and "currState" is an enum state variable.  When I run this code in the debugger, and listening is true, the sequence of steps is exactly as it should be (that is, the `setText()` and `setVisibility()` methods for both rtButton2 and rtButton3 are executed, however visibility for the the two buttons is never affected.

Any help?

Comment: post some code we can't figure out what you are doing wrong!!

Comment: there is nothing we can do without code.

Comment: I think you could speculate, but here goes...

Answer (score 0):

could it be like you are setting your textColor and background to black or white, which matches with your activity or containers background color that could be either black or white.. so everything matching with your background and looking invisible?

I fairly doubt these two lines of code.

```
rtButton2.setTextColor (DF_VIEW == currState ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
rtButton2.setBackgroundDrawable (DF_VIEW == currState ? tr_black : tr_white);
```

set color of button Text and Background to the one that donot match with your containers color.

regards,
Aqif hamid

Comment: Thanks, but my buttons are transparent with white or black borders and text (depending on currState).  They're not the same color as the background, they're really not there at all.  Strangely, changing the order I'm handling the various controlling variables seems to be having an impact (which I can't explain), but I'll keep poking away at it...